# What is the advantage of doing a Multi-GPU training in TensorFlow?

Tags: optimization, gpu, tensorflow, multi-gpu

In [this TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html), you can use N number of GPUs to distribute N mini-batches (each containing M training samples) to each GPU and calculate the gradients concurrently.

Then you average the gradients collected from N GPUs and update the model parameters.

But this has the same effect as using a single GPU to calculate the gradients of N*M training samples, then updating the parameters.

So the only advantage seems to me is that you can use a larger-sized mini-batch in the same amount of time.

But is the larger-sized mini-batch necessarily better?

I thought you shouldn't use a large-sized mini-batch, in order to make the optimization more robust to saddle points.

If the larger-sized mini-batch is indeed not better, why would you care about Multi-GPU learning, or even Multi-server learning?

(The tutorial above is a synchronous training. If it was asynchronous training, then I can see the merit, since the parameters will be updated without averaging the gradients calculated by each GPU)

Comment: Larger mini-batches aren't necessary better, but neither are smaller mini-batches.  The optimal choice of batch size is heavily dependent on various factors.

Comment: Let's say you are bounded to 1,000 samples per GPU because of the VRAM size. And let's assume the optimal mini-batch size is 2,000. Then in this synchronous multi-gpu setting, There should NOT be any advantage in using more than 2 GPUs. Right?

Comment: I would think that, to the contrary, you could theoretically (but not practically) benefit from 2000 GPUs, each computing the gradients of a single example.  Realistically, GPUs utilize a considerable amount of parallelism to begin with, but nevertheless, I would expect to see performance improvements by distributing the computation between (for example) 4 GPUs (each responsible for computing the gradients of 500 samples per batch).

Comment: That is a valid point. Running 500 training sample will be considerably faster than running 1,000 samples.

Comment: Why average the gradients？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose for multi-GPU learning is to enable you train on large data set in shorter time. It is not necessarily better with larger mini-batch, but at least you can finish learning in a more feasible time.

More precisely, those N mini-batches are not trained in a synchronized way if you use Asynchronous SGD algorithm. As the algorithm changes when using multi-GPU, it is not equal to using MxN size mini-batch on single-GPU with SGD algorithm.

If you use sync multi-GPU training, the benefit is mainly time reduction. You could use M/N-size mini-match to maintain the effective mini-batch size, and of course the scalability is limited as smaller mini-batch size leads to more overhead. Data-exchange and synchronization on large number of computing nodes are also disasters.

Finally to solve the scalability issue, people move to A-SGD when using large number of GPUs concurrently. So probably you won't see someone using sync multi-GPU training on hundreds of (or even tens of) GPUs.

Comment: So, in the extreme case where you have infinite number of GPUs, you can break the entire training sample into mini-batches and distribute them to infinite GPUs. Then, averaging the gradients calculated by infinite GPUs and updating the parameters will be exactly the same as "batch learning". There is nothing stochastic about this. But this is okay, because we can still train the model in a feasible time, even if we have a very large training sample. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I understand that asynchronous multi-gpu training is a different story. In this post, I am focusing on synchronous multi-gpu training.

Comment: @mp2893, ok, for sync multi-gpu training, the benefit is time reduction. But you could use M/N-size mini-match to maintain the effective mini-batch size, and of course the scalability is limited.

Comment: Why average the gradients？

Comment: @不是phd的phd : see this answer https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33489/why-averaging-the-gradient-works-in-gradient-descent?newreg=edaaa18740764d54ab0363c4268a6b9b

Comment: @kangshiyin is it even possible to do asynchronous multi-GPU training, without going through CPU? My understanding is that nobody has succeeded doing that.

Answer (score 0):

More gpu means more data in a batch. And the gradients of a batch data is averaged for back-propagation.

If the learning rate of a batch is fixed, then the learning rate of a data is smaller.

If the learning rate of a data is fixed, then the learning rate of a batch is larger.

https://github.com/guotong1988/BERT-GPU